# Filter PySpark column with array containing text

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, filtering

I want to do something like this:

```
is_even = lambda x: x % 2 == 0
res = df.withColumn("arr_evens", filter(col("some_arr"), is_even))
res.show()

+---------------+---------+
|       some_arr|arr_evens|
+---------------+---------+
|[1, 2, 3, 5, 7]|      [2]|
|      [2, 4, 9]|   [2, 4]|
+---------------+---------+
```

but I have an array with words and I want to filter them to get only those words that i have specified on list and i do not know how to define the lambda function...

I tried x.isin(list) but i got an error: TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: Can you add your input data and expected output?

Comment: It is exactly something like in the answer from Bibzon. I have list_of_words = ["word1", "word2", "word3"], input = ["word1", "word4", "word5"], expected_output = ["word1"]. Input and output are columns of pyspark dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with the **array_intersect** function. You do not need to use a lambda function. First lit a new column with the list, than the array_intersect function can be used to return the intersection of the two arrays.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
# create dataframe with words of array
data = [
    (["Hello", "World", "!"],)
]

list_of_words = ["World"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["words"])

# add list_of_words as a column
df = df.withColumn("list_of_words", fn.array(*map(fn.lit, list_of_words)))
df.show()

# +-----------------+-------------+
# |            words|list_of_words|
# +-----------------+-------------+
# |[Hello, World, !]|      [World]|
# +-----------------+-------------+


# get common_words
df = df.withColumn("common_words", fn.array_intersect("words", "list_of_words"))
df.show()

# +-----------------+-------------+------------+
# |            words|list_of_words|common_words|
# +-----------------+-------------+------------+
# |[Hello, World, !]|      [World]|     [World]|
# +-----------------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Bibzon will work fine. However if the matching list variable `list_of_words` is very large, it will consume a lot of memory of workers because the variable is duplicated in a column by the `lit` function. I think the PySpark program can be simple like the one below by referring to the matching list variable from outside of the UDF function.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def main():

    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .master('local-cluster[2,1,1024]') \ 
        .appName('array_matching').getOrCreate()

    data = [
        (["B", "E", "D", "S", "N"],),
        (["A", "C", "M", "G", "O", "E"],),
        (["M", "G", "O", "E"],)
    ]

    schema = StructType([
        StructField('word_array', ArrayType(StringType()))
    ])

    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

    matching_set = set(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
    
    def match(target_col):
        match_list = list(set(target_col).intersection(street_set))
        return match_list

    match_udf = udf(match, ArrayType(StringType()))

    df.withColumn("match_array", match_udf(col("word_array"))).show()
    
    spark.stop()
```

Input:

```
+------------------+
|        word_array|
+------------------+
|   [B, E, D, S, N]|
|[A, C, M, G, O, E]|
|      [M, G, O, E]|
+------------------+
```

Output:

```
+------------------+-----------+
|        word_array|match_array|
+------------------+-----------+
|   [B, E, D, S, N]|     [B, D]|
|[A, C, M, G, O, E]|     [C, A]|
|      [M, G, O, E]|         []|
+------------------+-----------+
```

If you want to know the scope and life cycle of a variable across a cluster, you can refer to the Spark document "Understanding closures" ( https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-).